Find $x$ such that $\sin(4x)\cdot\sin(8x)=\sin(3x)\cdot\sin(5x), 0<x<\pi/2$
$\sin(4x)\cdot\sin(8x)=\sin(3x)\cdot\sin(5x), \ 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$,  find x
I tried angle addition and subtraction formulas but failed.
I think $3x+5x = 8x = 4x \times 2$ would be a clue to solving a problem. But I can't  go further.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I'd say $8=4+4$ and $3=4-1$ and $5=4+1$. Just a guess.

$\sin(4x)(2\sin(4x)\cos(4x)=\sin(4x-x)\sin(4x+x)$

I tried this $2\sin(4x)^2\cos(4x)=\cos(x)^2 - \cos(4x)^2$  but it wasn't simple

As the comments have pointed out,
$$\sin4x\sin8x=\sin3x\sin5x$$
$$\implies2\sin^24x\cos4x=\sin^24x-\sin^2x$$
$$\implies\sin^24x(2\cos4x-1)=-\sin^2x$$
$$\implies16\sin^2x\cos^2x\cos^22x(2(2\cos^22x-1)-1)=-\sin^2x$$
Since $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right)\implies \sin x\ne0$, the factor of $\sin^2x$ can be cancelled from both sides:
$$\implies16\cos^2x\cos^22x(2(2\cos^22x-1)-1)=-1$$
$$\implies16\cos^2x\cos^22x(4\cos^22x-3)=-1$$
$$\implies8(1+\cos2x)\cos^22x(4\cos^22x-3)=-1$$
Taking $t=\cos2x$, the equation becomes:
$$8(1+t)(4t^4-3t^2)=-1$$
$$\implies 32t^5+32t^4-24t^3-24t^2+1=0$$
Now, I suppose you can proceed further.

We have that by product to sum formulas
$$\sin(3x)\cdot\sin(5x)=\frac12 \left(\cos (2x)-\cos (8x)\right)$$
$$\sin(4x)\cdot\sin(8x)=\frac12 \left(\cos (4x)-\cos (12x)\right)$$
therefore
$$\sin(4x)\cdot\sin(8x)=\sin(3x)\cdot\sin(5x) \iff \cos (2x)-\cos (4x)-\cos (8x)+\cos (12x)=0$$
and by double/triple-angle formulas by $0<\sqrt t=\cos x<1$ we obtain

$\cos(2x)=2t-1$
$\cos (4x)=2\cos^2(2x)^2-1=8t^2 - 8 t + 1$
$\cos (8x)=2\cos^2(4x)^2-1=128 t^4 - 256 t^3 + 160 t^2 - 32 t + 1$
$\cos (12x)=4\cos^3(4x)-3\cos (4x)=2048 t^{6} - 6144 t^{5} + 6912 t^4 - 3584 t^3 + 840 t^2 - 72 t + 1$

which leads to
$$1024 t^{6} - 3072 t^{5} + 3392 t^4 - 1664 t^3 + 336 t^2 - 15 t - 1=0$$
which has trivial root $t= 1$, not acceptable as solutions, and reduces to
$$1024 t^{5} - 2048 t^4 + 1344 t^3 - 320 t^2 + 16 t + 1=0$$
which can be solved numerically in the interval $t\in(0,1)$, leading to the solutions

$\cos x\approx 0.367460$
$\cos x\approx 0.614450$
$\cos x\approx 0.771927$
$\cos x\approx 0.962424$

